# Xcode 6 important button is out of reach and can't be moved?

Tags: xcode, button, interface-builder

Okay, so I have this button in my project and it is very important to the entirety of the code. Anyway, during the placing and constraining process, I somehow moved this button to the very top of the view controller just above the status bar. When I try to click on it and move it, I instead select the view controller. I have looked everywhere for a solution but it seems no one is having this same issue. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

Click on the button item in the list on the left, and then in the Size Inspector (next to the attributes inpector) change the height to some insanely big number. You will then be able to move it down.

Comment: Wow, sure did the trick! Thank you very much for the speedy answer! As my first time using this forum, I definitely was not expecting my question to even be seen. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! My pleasure.